# RestKit: Sending particular JSON, Please help, i've tried everything I can think of

Tags: ios, json, restkit

all ...

I've spent all weekend on this and the problem still happens. I don't know what else to do and any help would be very much appreciated. I'm trying to send JSON like this:

```
 { 
    "proof": 
    {
      "name":"fluff",
      "media_type":"Photo",
      "description":"This is a description"
    },
    "auth_token":"mphxNcEGJMJyU7iPmaLw"
 }
```

I keep getting the following exception from RestKit:

2012-07-23 10:29:17.001 restkittest[8389:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key auth_token.'

I suspect it's because the auth_token isn't a part of the object (proof) i'm passing, but I don't know how to pass the auth_token along with the proof since postObject only takes one object to post.

... and this is my code to try to do it:

```
@implementation proof
@synthesize name;
@synthesize description;
@synthesize media_type;
@synthesize duration;
@synthesize frequency_id;
@end

@implementation auth_token
@synthesize auth_token;
@end

- (BOOL)createProof:(proof *)proof
{
    BOOL ret = NO;

    [self.objectManager postObject:proof usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader *loader)
     {
         loader.delegate = self;

         RKObjectMapping *proofMappingAccept = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[proof class]];
         [proofMappingAccept mapKeyPath:@"name" toAttribute:@"name"];
         [proofMappingAccept mapKeyPath:@"description" toAttribute:@"description"];
         [proofMappingAccept mapKeyPath:@"media_type" toAttribute:@"media_type"];
         [proofMappingAccept mapKeyPath:@"duration" toAttribute:@"duration"];

         RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[NSMutableDictionary class]];

         [mapping mapKeyPath:@"auth_token" toAttribute:@"auth_token"];
         [mapping mapKeyPath:@"proof" toRelationship:@"proof" withMapping:proofMappingAccept];

         loader.serializationMapping = [mapping inverseMapping];

         loader.objectMapping = mapping;
     }];

    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an NSDictionary with your proof object as a value for the key "proof" and your auth_token as an object for the key "auth_token" and set loader.sourceObject to be this dictionary.